# Bootstrap's dropdown with glyphicons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on select-like control that is built with Bootstrap's dropdown component. You can look at it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nzl06I5u4sP6vFuoCNEs?p=preview). Selected options are marked with `ok` glyphicon.

I am facing rather strange problem. Steps to reproduce:

1. Open dropdown and select some options

   [image]
2. Note that all text labels are aligned equally
3. Close and open dropdown again
4. Text in previously selected options is slightly shifted.

   [image]

Tested in Chrome 54/55.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to `inline-block` property. Use `display: flex` property on `li.selected`. Like:

```
li.selected {
  display: flex;
}
```

I've updated your **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0qHIWp31kahcMFZTaORv)** code. Please have a look.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works like a charm! Can you say why it behaves in this way?

Comment: @SergeySokolov Its the property of `flexbox`, it just creates 0 space in-between its child elements, whereas `inline-block` creates around 2px between its elements. Learn more about flexbox - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: But why does it shift only after close/open?

Comment: @SergeySokolov On click it renders it on the spot, but after reopening it the items are adjusted again and the whole html re-renders, so maybe you can say the browser renders it again with the combination on `inline-block` & `block` elements. It is browser specific, try it on firefox, firefox will distort it as soon as you select the element. Hope you understand!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
.open>.dropdown-menu {
    padding: 5px;
}

li.selected {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Working fine for me.